# Reload page from server when session expires

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc, session

My application is ASP.NET MVC.
Some elements on the page are displyed only for authenticated users (for example, button for ordering product). But when session expires (the button is still displayed on page) and user orders product, server won't have information about user (user name) so will be error. 
**I want that some elements (button for ordering product) become hidden when session expires. It will be good to reload the whole page from server to refresh all elements. Maybe there is another way via javasript.**

Comment: Why not redirect to login/logoff page when their authentication expires?

Comment: @TheGeekYouNeed, I don't have such page. Everything in a single page. When user sign in (inputs his user name), new elements are added in page as for authenticated user. But when session expires, these elements are still displayed on page that's why I want to reload whole page from server. Perhaps, there is another way via javascript. I this case I just want to know if user session is alive.